# How to send Timestamp

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

I am using firestore database. And I want to send a timestamp whenever I click on the button in javascript.

When button clicked so the following function is calling:

```
function sendDataToApprove() {
  var getId=localStorage.getItem("getId");
  alert(getId);
var res = db.collection('Applications').doc(getId).update("Approved", true, "Pending", false);

// var myTimestamp = firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date());

Swal.fire({
  title:'Approved!',
  text: 'You Approved Your Policy',
  type: 'success',
    }).then(function() {
window.location = "dashboard.html";
});
}
```

Comment: You seem to already have the right construct in your code with `firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date())`. If you use that, what isn't working about it?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I do not know what to do next I used that but what should I do now? u mean this one line code is enough?

Comment: can you tell use what is the issue, are you getting an error, the data send is empty, the function is not called when you click the button ?